# DocuSign Add image into the Dynamic content

Tags: docusignapi

We are creating the Dynamic Content which are send in the DocuSign envelope.

Currently we are trying to add the image. But when we added the image in DocuSign envelope it is not getting render on DocuSign when customer get that pdf for sign.

Any one can suggest approach or any article that will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have an image linked from an outside source to be shown in the signing to signers. This is a security issue. Viruses and other malware can be inserted via images.
You have to send the image to DocuSign.
If the image is embedded in an HTML, than you must create a "flat" copy of the HTML that includes the image inline, not as a reference to a file on the web.
You can still generate it dynamically from your code. You just need to download the bits of the image and include them in the payload that is sent to DocuSign when the document is added.

Do something like this in your HTML (encode the image first with base64)

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////
wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4ML
wWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw=="
alt="Base64 encoded image" width="150" height="150"/>
```